# ¿Cómo concatenar filas en postgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Buenas como va? he estado buscando en internet pero no encuentro la respuesta.
Yo tengo una base de datos con este esquema:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es obtener las 3 categorías mas rentables por país, con la forma de  una tabla con una columna donde se enlisten los países y otra columna donde figuren las 3 categorías mas rentables de cada país separadas por coma "categoría1, categoría2, categoría3".

Yo he logrado con el siguiente código obtener las 3 categorías mas rentables de cada país pero cada una en una fila (adjunto imagen) y no logro concatenar las 3 filas por país en una sola separados por una coma. Si alguien me puede ayudar estaría agradecido.

```
WITH most_rentable_movies AS ( SELECT SUM(amount) - replacement_cost profits,
title
FROM payment
LEFT JOIN rental USING (rental_id)
LEFT JOIN inventory USING (inventory_id)
LEFT JOIN film USING (film_id)
GROUP BY title,
replacement_cost
ORDER BY profits DESC),
most_rentable_categories AS (SELECT name,
SUM(profits) revenues
FROM most_rentable_movies
JOIN film USING (title)
JOIN film_category USING (film_id)
JOIN category USING (category_id)
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY revenues DESC),
most_rentable_movies_bycountry AS (SELECT country,
name 
FROM country 
JOIN city USING (country_id)
JOIN address USING (city_id)
JOIN customer USING (address_id)
JOIN payment USING (customer_id)
JOIN rental USING (rental_id)
JOIN inventory USING (inventory_id)
JOIN film USING (film_id)
JOIN film_category USING (film_id)
JOIN category USING (category_id)
INNER JOIN most_rentable_categories USING (name)
GROUP BY country,
name
ORDER BY country DESC),
TOPTHREE AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() 
    over (
        PARTITION BY country
        order by country
    ) AS RowNo 
    FROM most_rentable_movies_bycountry
) SELECT * FROM TOPTHREE WHERE RowNo <= 3
```

[image: resultado obtenido]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes valerte de la función `string_agg()` ([documentación](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/functions-aggregate.html)), que hace justo lo que necesitas, concatenar las filas que pertenezcan al grupo utilizando un separador, en tu caso, sugeriría usar la coma.

Entonces, puedes sustituir tu consulta final por algo como:

```
SELECT country, string_agg(name, ', ') categories
  FROM TOPTHREE 
 WHERE RowNo <= 3
 GROUP BY country
```

Comment: anduvo perfectamente maestro gracias!!!!!

Comment: ¡Un gusto ser de ayuda!